# Setting querystring to APIGateway from AWS CDK

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I create translation api service using *Amazon Translate*.
Now, I want setting APIGateay from AWS CDK but I have no ideas for setting querystring.
Specifically, I want to make like this.

```
/translate?text=hello
```

I attach cdk source about APIGateway.

```
api = apigw.RestApi(
    self, "TranslatorApi",
    default_cors_preflight_options = apigw.CorsOptions(
        allow_origins = apigw.Cors.ALL_ORIGINS,
        allow_methods = apigw.Cors.ALL_METHODS
    )
)

tl = api.root.add_resource("translate")
tl.add_method(
    "GET",
    apigw.LambdaIntegration(get_translate_lambda)
)
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

The query string values is handled inside your lambda function

```py
def lambda_handler(event, context):
  text = event['queryStringParameters']['text']
```